# XPath Cannot locate element using text()

Tags: text, xpath

following code:

```
<label>
<input class="class1" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
                First text             
</label>
<label>
<input class="class2" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
                Second text             
</label>
<label>
<input class="class3" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
                Third text             
</label>
```

What I want to do is to get specific label element by containing text. I was trying:

```
//label[text()='First text']
```

and

```
//label[contains(text(),'First text')]
```

but it doesnt work.

Please, advise!

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//label[text()[contains(., 'First text')]]
```

---

Your attempt

```
//label[contains(text(),'First text')]
```

does not work because the `<label>` in

```
<label>[
]<input class="class1" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>[
                First text             
]</label>
```

has **two** text nodes: an empty one containing nothing but a line break, right before the `input`, and a non-empty one after the `<input>`. I've outlined them with square brackets above.

- A call like `contains(node-set, string)` forces a conversion of the first argument to `contains` to string.
- Converting a node-set to string gives you the text content of the *first node* of the set. (Try it out, `string(label)` will give you `'First text'` with a bunch of whitespace, no matter how many labels there are.)
- And in your case, that's the empty text node, so `contains(text(),'First text')` will never succeed.

Therefore you must test the text nodes individually, and that's done by nesting predicates like shown above.